# 404 Error when trying to load locale in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a locale in an Angular 5 project ran from within VS 2015. Reading the docs, i see that in order to add a locale, i should add the following in the app.module:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

...

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);
```

Unfortunately when loading the project i get an error of:

```
Error: Fetch error: 404 
  Instantiating https://localhost:44334/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/locales/fr
  Loading https://localhost:44334/app/app.module.js
  Loading app/main.js
    at fetch.js:37
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at <anonymous>
```

What puzzles me is that it tries to find the locale under bundles folder when i have requested it from the locales folder.

**Edit**

This is my `systemjs.config.js` file.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
      '@angular/locale/el': 'npm:@angular/common/locales/el.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how VS2015 sets up an angular project.  Do you know if you are using SystemJS or Webpack?

Comment: Or are you using angular-cli?

Comment: I suspect it uses SystemJS. Then he needs to add `map` to `@angular/common/locales` and also transpile locale file because it's distributed as ES module

Comment: I have a systemjs

Comment: I have already added this line in there: `'@angular/locale/el': 'npm:@angular/common/locales/el.js'`

Comment: Can you try adding this rule?     `'@angular/common/locales': 'npm:@angular/common/locales'`

Comment: Please post your config

Comment: Can you also tell us SystemJS version you're using?

Comment: I will as soon as i get to my office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using locales from angular package requires additional configuration for SystemJS because they are not included in main bundle, don't have dedicated bundle.

They are also shipped as ES modules that has to be transpiled

### SystemJS 0.19.x

Simple version:

```typescript
System.config({
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
  },

  transpiler: 'typescript', // we need this to transpile locales

  map: {
    ...
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/locales': 'npm:@angular/common/locales',
    ...
    'typescript': 'https://unpkg.com/typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js'
                                               ^^^^^^^
                                              required
  },
  packages: {
    ...
    '@angular/common/locales': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/noKZoYCEM0zlo6Ci8BT8?p=preview)** (I also tested it locally)

If you don't want to use typescript@2.2.1(but rather > 2.2.1) and get it from unpkg.com then you consider the following config.

A slightly complicated version 0.19.x:

```typescript
System.config({
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
  },

  transpiler: 'typescript',

  map: {
    ...
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/locales': 'npm:@angular/common/locales',
    ...
    'typescript': 'npm:/typescript', // assuming typescript > 2.2.1
  },
  packages: {
    ...
    '@angular/common/locales': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    "typescript": {
      "main": "lib/typescript.js",
      "meta": {
        "lib/typescript.js": {
          "exports": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker SystemJS@0.19.x, typescript@2.6.2](https://plnkr.co/edit/SG8nuGQqICtyAoglHOp0?p=preview)** (tested locally)

### SystemJS 0.20.x

There were a lot of breaking changes so you must configure special plugin  https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript

1) Install plugin

```typescript
npm i -D plugin-typescript
```

2) Change config like:

```typescript
System.config({
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
  },

  transpiler: 'ts-plugin',

  map: {
    ...
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/locales': 'npm:@angular/common/locales',
    ...
    'typescript': 'npm:/typescript',
    'ts-plugin': 'npm:plugin-typescript'
  },
  packages: {
    ...
    '@angular/common/locales': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },

    "ts-plugin": {
      "main": "lib/plugin.js"
    },
    "typescript": {
      "main": "lib/typescript.js",
      "meta": {
        "lib/typescript.js": {
          "exports": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see now we use `plugin-typescipt` instead of just typescipt. But internally this plugin requires `typescipt` so we should also keep it in our config

**[Plunker SystemJS@0.20.x typescript@2.6.2](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ki2woekTOqbVQgN2PgMZ?p=preview)** (tested locally)

Comment: One question, VS has its own typescript and i see it is version 2.2.2. How can i make systemjs use the same one in order to not have to remember changing this in both places in a future update?

Comment: Perhaps second config will work for you if you're on systemjs 0.19

Comment: Checked my package.json. I am on "systemjs": "0.20.19".

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error: expected expression, got '<'
  Evaluating https://localhost:44334/typescript
  Evaluating https://localhost:44334/node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib/plugin.js
  Loading ts-plugin
  Unable to load transpiler to transpile https://localhost:44334/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/el.js`

Comment: Did copy my last config? Can you post your stripped down project somewhere so i can check it?

Comment: I will create a sample and let you know. But i have to do this later in the evening. (I do have the feeling that doing so will make me see where am i wrong ;) )

Comment: Hi, i just wanted to say i have nor abandoned this, but it was a crazy couple of days and i have not managed to do so yet....

Comment: I just created a sample project and it works as expected when i used your last option. I will mark it as the answer and give you the bounty. Even if i still have the issue in the orriginal project, it is clearly out of scope of this question. Thanks a lot for the help.